# My android app should not run in background, it means should not restore

Tags: android

Whenever the user presses the home button, the application will run in background in android 4.4. In my application, i dont wanna that background activity. My entire app should close, by clicking the home button.

Comment: Great! What do we do now ?

Comment: Why do you want to prevent it from going to background? That is the way android works by default. There must be another way around to your solution.

Answer (score 1):

in your Activites onPause() function put finish();